# Syntax error for permission.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am not able to solve this syntax error I have on permission.rb. It says it needs a extra "end" but when I do add it Safari is unable to load the page. I have tried several different methods on both files, none seem to work. Any ideas?

Error:

```
    SyntaxError in UsersController#new

/Users/lexi87/dating/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:20: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
Rails.root: /Users/lexi87/dating

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

permission.rb (without the extra 'end'):

```
class Permission < Struct.new(:user)
  def allow?(controller, action)
    if user.nil?
      controller == "galleries" && action.in?(%w[index show])
    elsif user.admin?
      true
    else
      controller == "galleries" && action != "destroy"
    end
  end
```

application_controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

private

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
  helper_method :current_user

  def current_permission
    @current_permission || ::Permission.new(current_user)
  end
end
  def authorize
    if !current_permission.allow?(params[:controller], params[:action])
      redirect_to root_url, alert: "Not authorized."
    end
  end
end
```

**UPDATE**

```
Here's my users_controller:

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authorize

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def profile
    @profile = User.profile
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      UserMailer.registration_confirmation(@user).deliver
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Thank you for signing up!"
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

    def edit
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def destroy
     User.find(params[:id]).destroy
     flash[:success] = "User deleted."
     redirect_to users_url
   end

def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:success] = "Account updated"
      redirect_to @user
      authorize! :update, @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### corrections

**1.**

You definetely need the `end` at the end of the `permission.rb`

**2.**

you do not need and end to end the **private** section of `ApplicationController`. Everything below the private keyword is considered 'private'. So you need to move the "authorize" method.

### solution

So the complete code is (with moving one method into "public"):

permission.rb:

```
class Permission < Struct.new(:user)
  def allow?(controller, action)
    if user.nil?
      controller == "galleries" && action.in?(%w[index show])
    elsif user.admin?
      true
    else
      controller == "galleries" && action != "destroy"
    end
  end
end
```

application_controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  def authorize
    if !current_permission.allow?(params[:controller], params[:action])
      redirect_to root_url, alert: "Not authorized."
    end
  end

private

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
  helper_method :current_user

  def current_permission
    @current_permission || ::Permission.new(current_user)
  end

end
```

Comment: I get a failed to open page still with that.

Comment: Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Filter chain halted as :authorize rendered or redirected

Comment: which url are you trying to access? it seems to me that it redirects you to the root_url and you may not have permissions to access it OR there is nothing to display on your root_url. check your routes.rb where it goes and which controller and view it uses

Comment: I am accessing http://localhost:3000. You are right, when I remove  before_filter :authorize from the controllers the page loads. That's weird

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need another `end` in permission.rb **and** you need to move one in application_controller.rb:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

private

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
  helper_method :current_user

  def current_permission
    @current_permission || ::Permission.new(current_user)
  end
end  # this shouldn't be here
  def authorize
    if !current_permission.allow?(params[:controller], params[:action])
      redirect_to root_url, alert: "Not authorized."
    end
  end
# it should be here
```

Comment: Should also add it looks like maybe he doesn't want `authorize` to be private, so if that's the case, it should be moved above the previous `private` call or `public` should be used before it

Comment: I had it all below the private as that is how it was on rails cast. I place the extra end under current_permission as trying a new solution, originally I had it without. Safari fails to open page with that code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to close the `private` keyword.

The `end` after

```
def current_permission
```

is not necessary !

Comment: That gets me: /Users/lexi87/dating/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:19: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
  end